# How to use flutter_typeahead with FirestoreFirebase to generate suggestions?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
class Header extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HeaderState createState() => _HeaderState();
  Future<List> getSearch() async {
    List<String> searchList;
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents =
        (await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('movies').get()).docs;
    searchList = documents
        .map((documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot['movieName'] as String)
        .toList();
        print(searchList); //This does print the data from the database.
        
        
    return searchList;
  }
  
}
```

The above code fetches data from `FirebaseFirestore` and also the print statement prints the list fetched.

```
class _HeaderState extends State<Header> {
  final MenuController _controller = Get.put(MenuController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      color: kDarkBlackColor,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding),
              constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: kMaxWidth),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius:
                                new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white)),
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.menu,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _controller.openOrCloseDrawer();
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 7,
                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png')),

                      Spacer(),

                  
                      Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 5,
                          child: TypeAheadField(
                            hideOnEmpty: true,
                            textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                                autofocus: true,
                                style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context)
                                    .style
                                    .copyWith(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder())),
                            suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
                              return CitiesService.getSuggestions(pattern);
                            },
                            transitionBuilder:
                                (context, suggestionsBox, controller) {
                              return suggestionsBox;
                            },
                            itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
                              return ListTile(
                                title: Text(suggestion),
                              );
                            },
                            onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {},
                          )),
                      Spacer(),

                      Socal(),
                      //Spacer(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CitiesService {
  static List<String> search = Header().getSearch() as List<String>; //This is not adding data to list
  static List<String> getSuggestions(String query) {
    print(search); //This does not print any thing.
    List<String> matches = List();
    matches.addAll(search);

    matches.retainWhere((s) => s.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()));
    return matches;
  }
}
```

I am trying to store the data fetched in `getSearch()` into search List so that I can use it to provide suggestions but the list is empty. I don't know if this is the correct way to convert future into list of strings. Help would be really appreciated. Also, if there is another way to implement search from `FirebaseFirestore`, please do let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `getSearch` is an async function, which mean that it return intially a Future while is awaiting the async part of the function to be fulfilled and continue to execute, so in order to capture that you should be using a `future.then()` notation, doing something like this while calling `getSearch` will fix the issue:

```
Header().getSearch().then((value) {
    static List<String> search = value as List<String>;
    ...
});
```

Comment: Hi @WytrzymałyWiktor. Actually I tried doing what was suggested but it didn't solve the problem. I am still not getting the List. It might be because of my code structure or I missed putting something in the main() function. I've been trying since 2 weeks but no luck.

Comment: Can you try logging something inside the `then()`, just to check if this is being triggered?